# App Engine to GCS | Uploading Issue

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have some files that I'm receiving from the Evernote API (via `getResource`) and writing to Google Cloud Storage with the following code:

```
gcs_file = gcs.open(filename, 'w', content_type=res.mime,
                    retry_params=write_retry_params)

# Retrieve the binary data and write to GCS
resource_file = note_store.getResource(res.guid, True, False, False, False)
gcs_file.write(resource_file.data.body)

gcs_file.close()
```

For even some types of documents, it still works.  But there are certain documents that GCS throws this in the logs:

```
Unable to fetch URL: https://storage.googleapis.com/evernoteresources/5db799f1-c03c-4056-812a-6d77bad55261/Sleep Away.mp3
```

and

```
Got exception while contacting GCS. Will retry in 0.11 seconds.
```

There doesn't seem to be any pattern to these errors.  It happens with documents, sounds, pictures, whatever - some of these document types work and some don't.  It isn't due to size (since some small work and some large do).

Any ideas?

---

Here's the full stack trace, though I'm not sure it will help.

```
Encountered unexpected error from ProtoRPC method implementation: TimeoutError (('Request to Google Cloud Storage timed out.', DownloadError('Unable to fetch URL: https://storage.googleapis.com/evernoteresources/78413585-2266-4426-b08c-71d6c224f266/Evernote Snapshot 20130512 124546.jpg',)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/protorpc/wsgi/service.py", line 181, in protorpc_service_app
    response = method(instance, request)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/endpoints/api_config.py", line 972, in invoke_remote
    return remote_method(service_instance, request)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/protorpc/remote.py", line 412, in invoke_remote_method
    response = method(service_instance, request)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~quinector/2a.368528733040360018/endpoints.py", line 61, in get_note_details
    url = tools.registerResource(note_store, req.note_guid, r)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~quinector/2a.368528733040360018/GlobalUtilities.py", line 109, in registerResource
    retry_params=write_retry_params)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~quinector/2a.368528733040360018/cloudstorage/cloudstorage_api.py", line 69, in open
    return storage_api.StreamingBuffer(api, filename, content_type, options)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~quinector/2a.368528733040360018/cloudstorage/storage_api.py", line 526, in __init__
    status, headers, _ = self._api.post_object(path, headers=headers)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~quinector/2a.368528733040360018/cloudstorage/rest_api.py", line 41, in sync_wrapper
    return future.get_result()
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 325, in get_result
    self.check_success()
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 368, in _help_tasklet_along
    value = gen.throw(exc.__class__, exc, tb)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~quinector/2a.368528733040360018/cloudstorage/storage_api.py", line 84, in do_request_async
    'Request to Google Cloud Storage timed out.', e)
TimeoutError: ('Request to Google Cloud Storage timed out.', DownloadError('Unable to fetch URL: https://storage.googleapis.com/evernoteresources/78413585-2266-4426-b08c-71d6c224f266/Evernote Snapshot 20130512 124546.jpg',))
```

Comment: Both of the errors you posted have spaces in the paths. Is that true for all of the cases where you see errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the gcs client code. It should properly handle the filename. The fact it is using http request to GCS should be "hidden". This will be fixed soon. Thanks!

Note if you quote the filename yourself to work around this bug, the filename will be double quoted after the fix. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Brian! The problem was the spaces in the filenames.  I just used `urllib2.quote()` to get those out of there and it works like a charm.